# How to store structs in a SharedArray in Julia?

Tags: struct, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, julia, shared-memory

So I have a situation where I want to store a large array of data as a shared array so I can do some parallelism on the data. However, the arrays is an array of types. When I try to initialize it as `SharedArray` though, I get an error saying that it must be a bit type. My question is how can I have a normal struct be considered a bit type in Julia so that it may be used by `SharedArray`? Or do I have to do some weird conversion where I convert my object to an string/integer in array and the deserialize it in each child process?

Here is the type I am trying store

```
type Rating
    user::Int32
    item::Int32
    value::Float32
end
```

Now I, I know I could try to break this up into parrallel arrays, but that would require that rewrite large portions of the code and I'd rather not do that. As such, is there any other way I can store this struct or in an `SharedArray`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make it an [immutable](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#immutable-composite-types), then you should be able to store it in the `SharedArray`.

```
immutable Rating
    user::Int32
    item::Int32
    value::Float32
end
```

makes a "plain data" immutable structure, i.e.,
one for which `isbits` function returns `true`.